# How to upload videos in Youtube using refreshtoken in java

Tags: java, youtube-api, google-oauth

I am trying to upload videos to Youtube with authorization code.

```
    
public  Credential authorize(List scopes, String credentialDatastore) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        // Load client secrets.
        URI filePath = new URI (GOOGLE_APIKEY);
        Reader clientSecretReader =new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath.toString()));

        //Reader clientSecretReader = new InputStreamReader(Auth.class.getResourceAsStream(GOOGLE_APIKEY));
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, clientSecretReader);



        // Checks that the defaults have been replaced (Default = "Enter X here").
        if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter")
                || clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("Enter ")) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Enter Client ID and Secret from https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/apiui/credential "
                            + "into src/main/resources/client_secrets.json");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // This creates the credentials datastore at ~/.oauth-credentials/${credentialDatastore}
        FileDataStoreFactory fileDataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/" + CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY));
        DataStore datastore = fileDataStoreFactory.getDataStore(credentialDatastore);

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, scopes).setCredentialDataStore(datastore).build();

        // Build the local server and bind it to port 8080
        LocalServerReceiver localReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8080).build();

        // Authorize.
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, localReceiver).authorize("user");
    }
```

This is working and the user has to authenticate everytime when the video will be uploaded.
Now I want the to upload videos using the accesstoken generated from the refreshtoken which I already have .
But need to integrate in my Auth file which has the LocalServerReceiver as uses Jetty server internally.

I have written the code to get the accesstoken from refresh token .Please help me to integrate it .

```
 
 public GoogleCredential getCredentials(String clientId,String clientSecret,JsonFactory jsonFactory,HttpTransport transport,String refreshToken) throws IOException{

        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret)
                .setTransport(transport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .build();
        credential.setRefreshToken(refreshToken);

        // Do a refresh so we can fail early rather than return an unusable credential

            credential.refreshToken();
        String authCode=credential.getAccessToken();
        return credential;

    }
```

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31737699/upload-videos-to-youtube-from-my-web-server-in-java) if it can help you.

Comment: I have overcome the problem by writing a class extending the google's AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp class and customised the whole authentication process flow by breaking in three different method
1.getAuthorizationFromStorage
2.getAuthorizationFromGoogle
3.saveAuthorizationFromGoogle
[The implementation code] (https://github.com/soumik-dutta/youtube-upload-javaAPI) and the [extended class] (https://github.com/soumik-dutta/youtube-upload-javaAPI/blob/master/youtube/utils/ExtendedAuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java)

Comment: It is better if you post it as answer :)

Answer (score 3):

There was specifically two problems that I was facing during Youtube video upload using google-java-api

1. An instance of  **jetty server** instance  which will be listening constantly until the response       is coming from Google as mentioned in the redirect url.
2. Though there is a function called `setHost()` inside `new LocalServerReceiver.Builder()` class      which responsible for creating a local jetty server instance, was throughing a **Cannot assign       requested address** error everytime a host name was given irrespective of the port which did not matter.

The whole authorisation process is done in the  **AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp** class's authorize method whose primary functions are as follows

1. Create an url that will ask the user to give access to the app .
2. After successful authentication a code will be received (An instance of jetty server continuously listens untill the code is received ).
3. Exchange the code just received with the accesstoken and refreshtoken for offline upload.
4. Store the credentials that we just received from google.

To decouple the whole process I have created a new class **ExtendedAuthorizationCodeInstalledApp** which extends the original **AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp** and created each method for each functions in the class.The methods are as follows

1. **getAuthorizationFromStorage** : Get access token from stored credentials.
2. **getAuthorizationFromGoogle** : Get the authentication with the credentials from Google creates  the url that will lead the user to the authentication page and creating a custom defined name-value pair in the state parameter. The value should be encoded with base64 encoder so we can receive the same code redirected from google after authentication.
3. **saveAuthorizationFromGoogle** : Save the credentials that we get from  google.

   - Create the GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow object from the
     credentialDatastorfrom the response received from the google after
     authentication.
   - Hit google to get the permanent refresh-token that can be used to get
     the   accesstoken of the user any time .
   - Store the tokens like accesstoken and refreshtoken in the filename as
     userid

The code implementation is [here](https://github.com/soumik-dutta/youtube-upload-javaAPI/blob/master/youtube/utils/ExtendedAuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java)

Thanks @KENdi for your suggestion...